# Stop animation until specific drawable is displayed

Tags: android, animation

I have a AnimationDrawable which shows the numbers 0-9.

When the Activity is started, the animation starts, too.

it starts with 0, then 1,2,3 ....... and stops at picture "9";

How can I stop this little animation when f.e. "5" is displayed?

Is there any solution with a while-loop?

```
ImageView view = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv);
AnimationDrawable animation = (AnimationDrawable)iv.getBackground();
animation.start();
```

Comment: Some could would be useful. Which animation are You playing and how?

Comment: Have You tried to post (using new Handler().postDelayed()) for exact time of 5th frame and call stop()?

Comment: No, I didn't try it. I don't have any idea to realise my question

Comment: If you know the time when you call `start()`, the time of each frame until the target frame(with `getDuration(i)`) then you can calculate with some approximation when to call `stop()`(with a `Runnable`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to do it the following way:

```
    final ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);

    if (null != imageView) {
        final AnimationDrawable bgAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) imageView.getBackground();

        bgAnimation.start();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                bgAnimation.stop();
            }
        }, 5500);
    }
```

Assuming that You have animation xml like the following:

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false" >
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/choose12"
        android:duration="1000"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/choose12_1"
        android:duration="1000"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/choose12_2"
        android:duration="1000"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/choose12_3"
        android:duration="1000"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/choose12_4"
        android:duration="1000"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/choose12_5"
        android:duration="1000"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/choose12_6"
        android:duration="1000"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/choose12_7"
        android:duration="1000"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/choose12_8"
        android:duration="1000"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/choose12_9"
        android:duration="1000"/>
</animation-list>
```

However, this way will work not stable with small delays. So, I would suggest to take a look at [PropertyAnimation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html) if You need better control over animation process.